# While creating cost function in logistic regression getting "MATH DOMAIN ERROR"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to create Cost function for logistic regression .while passing the vlaues into that function i'm getting "MATH DOMAIN ERROR".

````
def Cost_Function(X,Y,theta,m):
    sumOfErrors = 0
    for i in range(m):
        xi = X[i]
        hi = Hypothesis(theta,xi)
        if Y[i] == 1:
            error = Y[i] * math.log(hi)
        elif Y[i] == 0:
            error = (1-Y[i]) * math.log(1-hi)
        sumOfErrors += error
    const = -1/m
    J = const * sumOfErrors
    print ('cost is ', J )
    return J```

<ipython-input-14-4cd33d7e280c> in Cost_Function(X, Y, theta, m)
      7             error = Y[i] * math.log(hi)
      8         elif Y[i] == 0:
----> 9             error = (1-Y[i]) * math.log(1-hi)
     10         sumOfErrors += error
     11     const = -1/m

ValueError: math domain error
````

Comment: This means that `1 - hi <= 0`

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring here. `error = (1-Y[i]) * math.log(1-hi)`

`log` operations are usually performed on numbers greater than 0. If you perform `log` on a number less than or equal to 0, the result is undefined. As a result, you are getting that exception.